# Why does my img show up when I hardcode the src URL, but not when I assign it programmatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, ecmascript-6, firebase-storage

I'm creating a practice React app, and am using Firebase Storage to pull an image from my Firebase Storage bucket and show it on the website. The image, however, does not appear, despite the fact that the image URL is properly assigned to 's src. However, when I copy/paste the image URL directly into the  src in JSX, everything shows up and works fine.

My console.log() message shows the correct image URL is received before rendering. Also, after the site has finished loading, running document.getElementsByClassName('Image').src in the developer tools console also shows the correct image URL. When I hardcode the image URL into the  src then everything works fine and the image displays.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {url: ''};  
    let storage = firebase.storage();
    let gsReference = storage.ref('blue.png');

    gsReference.getDownloadURL().then(url=> 
          {
              console.log("received URL: ", url); 
              this.setState({url: url})
          }
        );
  }


render() {

      document.getElementsByClassName('Image').src = this.state.url; 
      console.log("img URL: ", document.getElementsByClassName('Image').src);  

      return (
              <img src="" className='Image' /> 
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you let `App` component return `<img src={this.state.url} className="Image" />` ?

Comment: *The `getElementsByClassName` method of `Document` interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.* -- you're trying to set src on an array, not an img element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to see if it work for you

```
<img src={this.state.url} className="Image" />
```

Also set image src using document query is not a best practise